# How to resize LVM partition in my setup?

Tags: linux, centos, lvm, partition

I have a CentOS 6 VMware VPS with the current partition format :

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg_serverdl-lv_root
                       11G  4.9G  4.7G  52% /
tmpfs                 1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1             477M   88M  364M  20% /boot
```

I have asked my server provider to increase my space from 11 GB to 26 GB and I can confirm that using the command below :

```
fdisk -l /dev/sda

Disk /dev/sda: 26.8 GB, 26843545600 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 3263 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000087c2

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *           1          64      512000   83  Linux
Partition 1 does not end on cylinder boundary.
/dev/sda2              64        1567    12069888   8e  Linux LVM
```

This part confirms the change has been made by the hosting provider :

```
Disk /dev/sda: 26.8 GB, 26843545600 bytes
```

However , using the following command , I can't see this free space in VG details :

```
vgdisplay vg_serverdl
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               vg_serverdl
  System ID
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        1
  Metadata Sequence No  3
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                2
  Open LV               2
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                1
  Act PV                1
  VG Size               11.51 GiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              2946
  Alloc PE / Size       2946 / 11.51 GiB
  Free  PE / Size       0 / 0
  VG UUID               1cGbOQ-8ACV-SFk1-XJq6-cpNi-yxoh-uXZcop
```

I don't see the Free space in here :

```
  Alloc PE / Size       2946 / 11.51 GiB
  Free  PE / Size       0 / 0
```

How can I safely increase the / partition size from 11 G to 25 G in my setup ?

Answer (score 0):

Your volume group is already created with initial physical volume therefore showing space of the initial physical volume only.

I will suggest you to follow following steps:

1. Remove your  initial volume group.
2. Create a physical volume with the new disk spaces.
3. Create a volume group containing both the first and second physical volumes.

The new volume group thus created should show you the space you intended to get, you can create logical volumes out of it as per the need.

You can refer the below public document:
[1]: https://simonfredsted.com/1389

Answer (score 0):

Forgive me if this is not helpful, but this saved me when facing similar issue: https://www.tecmint.com/extend-and-reduce-lvms-in-linux/